# Richtextbox image with binding not working

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone-7, binding, richtextbox

**Goto Edited**

Since the Xaml property of the RichTextbox is not a dependency property I have created a customized RichTextbox where I can interact with its xaml property:

```
<local:RichTextUserControl RtfXaml="{Binding Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource RichTextBoxContentConverter}}" />
```

and I am Binding the following text to the xaml property and it is working fine:

```
<Section xml:space=\"preserve\" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste=\"False\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">
   <Paragraph FontSize=\"20\" FontFamily=\"Segoe WP\" Foreground=\"#FFFFFFFF\" FontWeight=\"Normal\" FontStyle=\"Normal\" FontStretch=\"Normal\" TextAlignment=\"Left\">
      <Run Text=\"Some text without formatting\" />
      <Italic>Some italic text</Italic> 
      <Underline>I am UnderLined</Underline>
   </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

I am binding with it trough a converter, where I search for smiley characters (for example :) ;) :D so on...) and replacing them with images, and if I insert the following code somewhere in-between the paragraph text it crashes:

```
<InlineUIContainer>
    <Image Source="ApplicationIcon.png"/>
</InlineUIContainer>
```

(It is only exception when it is with binding)

**Edited**:

So I found out this was a bad aproach, and I started to implement it this way:

```
<RichTextBox Tag="{Binding Path=MessageText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Loaded="loaded"/>

        private void loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                var richTextBox= sender as RichTextBox;
                Object o = XamlReader.Load(string.Format(XamlTemplate, richTextBox.Tag.ToString()));
                var section = o as Section;
                if (section  != null)
                {
                    richTextBox.Blocks.Clear();
                    var tempBlocks = section.Blocks.ToList();
                    section.Blocks.Clear();
                    foreach (Block block in tempBlocks)
                        richTextBox.Blocks.Add(block);
        }

private const string XamlTemplate = "<Section xml:space=\"preserve\" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste=\"False\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><Paragraph FontSize=\"20\" FontFamily=\"Segoe WP\" Foreground=\"#FFFFFFFF\" FontWeight=\"Normal\" FontStyle=\"Normal\" FontStretch=\"Normal\" TextAlignment=\"Left\"><Run Text=\"{0}\" /><Image Source=\"ApplicationIcon.png\" Width=\"15\" Height=\"15\"/></InlineUIContainer> </Paragraph></Section>";
```

So I am parsing the Xaml on the textboxs loaded event, with text and string. XamlTemplate is a hardcoded text with a smiley template.

My smiley is working this way, but when I scroll down in my listbox where there are numbers of these Richtextboxes, the scrolling starts jumping, and it is really annoying.

But when I change the listbox items to a fixed size it is working fine, but I need to change the sizes for the items dynamically, any ideas on that?

Comment: Where is your image located? This doesn't look like a valid URI.

Comment: it is on the root of the application

Comment: Hey.. Try to use longlistselector instead of listbox to reduce rendering problems.. And let me know the status..

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code.

```
    private Regex rxForbidden = new Regex(@"[<;]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    string[] stringArray;

    private void richTextbox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var richTextBox= sender as RichTextBox;
         string t = richTextBox.Tag.ToString();
         Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();

         if (rxForbidden.IsMatch(t))
         {
             s = rxForbidden.Split(t);
             richTextBox.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);

             for (int i = 0; i < s.Count(); i++)
             {

                 if (s[i] != null && s[i] != "")
                 {
                     Run txt = new Run();
                     txt.Text = s[i];
                     myParagraph.Inlines.Add(txt);

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Image MyImage = new Image();
                     MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/RichTextBoxText;component/smiley_72x72.png", UriKind.Relative));
                     MyImage.Height = 30;
                     MyImage.Width = 30;
                     InlineUIContainer MyUI = new InlineUIContainer();
                     MyUI.Child = MyImage;
                     myParagraph.Inlines.Add(MyUI);
                 }
             }
             richTextBox.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your image URI is invalid. 
It should be something like:

```
<InlineUIContainer>
    <Image Source="/YourApplication;component/ApplicationIcon.png"/>
</InlineUIContainer>
```

Comment: No this isn't the problem. In the meanwhile I found this: "Note that The XAML string returned by the Xaml property will not include any UIElement objects that are present in the content. The InlineUIContainer objects will be converted to empty Run objects." Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613(v=vs.95).aspx  Meaning I cannot add image through the xaml element, so I am trying a different approach now. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Ah that's true, I remember reading that as well now. In my application, I decided to put some (semi-trivial) code in the View to fill the RichTextBox instead of trying to data-bind it.